# how to use envoyloadbalancer to route Multiple domains on same public IP

Tags: proxy, microservices, devops, load-balancing, envoyproxy

here is my architecture
[architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG0Xw.png)

i want to bind multiple domains to same IP address
by exemple when i enter foo.com in my browser i see webapp1
and when i type bar.com in my broswer i find webapp2 .
for that i have two webapp :
**webapp1 on ip 1111:5000**

**webapp2 on ip 1111:6000**

here is my envoy version

```
envoy  version: d362e791eb9e4efa8d87f6d878740e72dc8330ac/1.18.2/clean-getenvoy-76c310e-envoy/RELEASE/BoringSSL
```

and here is my config envoy.yaml :

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 80
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          codec_type: AUTO
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: foo.com
              domains:
              - "foo.com"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/"
                route:
                  cluster: service_foo
            - name: bar.com
              domains:
              - "bar.com"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/"
                route:
                  cluster: service_bar
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.router
            typed_config: {}
  clusters:
  - name: service_foo
    connect_timeout: 1.00s
    type: strict_dns
    lb_policy: round_robin
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: service_foo
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: 1.1.1.1
                port_value: 5000
                ipv4_compat: true
  - name: service_bar
    connect_timeout: 1.00s
    type: strict_dns
    lb_policy: round_robin
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: service_bar
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: 1.1.1.1
                port_value: 6000
                ipv4_compat: true
  
admin:
  access_log_path: "/dev/null"
  address:
    socket_address:
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 8001
```

**when i enter in my browser foo.com work but bar.com does not work.
What is the issue please help me .**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the same Test with a slight difference in the YAML config file.

I think each service endpoint must be the internal Ip address (private).
Here is an example: I have two web apps running on docker: **start** on port 3000 and **blog** on 8080. docker image here: https://hub.docker.com/r/ang67/blog and https://hub.docker.com/r/ang67/getting-started

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 80
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          codec_type: AUTO
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: start.com
              domains:
              - "start.com"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/"
                route:
                  cluster: service_start
            - name: blog.com
              domains:
              - "blog.com"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/"
                route:
                  cluster: service_blog
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
            typed_config: {}
  clusters:
  - name: service_start
    connect_timeout: 1.00s
    type: strict_dns
    lb_policy: round_robin
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: service_start
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: 172.17.0.1
                port_value: 3000
                ipv4_compat: true
  - name: service_blog
    connect_timeout: 1.00s
    type: strict_dns
    lb_policy: round_robin
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: service_blog
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: 172.17.0.1
                port_value: 8080
                ipv4_compat: true
  
admin:
  access_log_path: "/dev/null"
  address:
    socket_address:
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 8001
```

Run the envoy on a container:

```
docker run --rm -it \
    -v $(pwd)/envoy-custom.yaml:/envoy-custom.yaml \
    -p 9901:9901 \
    -p 80:80 \
    envoyproxy/envoy-dev:2e6db8378477a4a63740746c5bfeb264cd76bc34 \
    -c /envoy-custom.yaml
```

Run:

> curl -H "Host: start.com" http://localhost
> curl -H "Host: blog.com" http://localhost

or do mapping in your etc/hosts for start.com and blog.com in order to launch in a browser

Comment: Yes i use internal Ip address (private) for service endpoint and it worked for me. thank you so much Bro